# inotify only acts upon modification by root

Tags: systemd, inotify

On my Debian Buster system I want to run a bash script when a certain file is modified. I have created and enabled a service in `/etc/systemd/system` which looks like this

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/watch_file.sh
Restart=always
RestartSec=1
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=backup-channels
User=root
Group=root

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and the file `watch_file.sh` looks like this

```
#!/bin/bash
while inotifywait -e close_write "path_to_watched_file"
do
    sh /usr/local/bin/action_to_perform.sh
done
```

All files are owned by the root user. Things are ok as long as the root user modifies the file. However, I would like to run the script as well when a non-root user modifies the file. Currently, a modification by a user different from root does not trigger the script `action_to_perform.sh`.

Comment: using inotifywait in a loop instead of monitor mode (-m) is prone to race conditions that can miss events.

Comment: @A.B Thanks! What would be a better solution then? I wan't the monitoring to be "permanent", that is, the monitoring process should not exit when a file modification has been noted.

Comment: check how you can use the -m option instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`inotifywait` doesn't care about effective UIDs/GIDs - it works on a different level.

The while loop you have here will terminate whenever `inotifywait` exits with a non-zero return status - perhaps that's your issue:

> EXIT STATUS
>
> 1      An  error occurred in execution of the program, or an event occurred which was not being listened for.  The latter generally occurs if something happens which forcibly removes the inotify watch, such as a watched file being deleted or the filesystem containing a watched file being unmounted.

Please try changing it to

```bsh
#! /bin/bash
while inotifywait -e close_write "path_to_watched_file"; true; do
    sh /usr/local/bin/action_to_perform.sh
done
```

It will burn CPU cycles if the file is not present, you can add `sleep 1` after the action_to_perform.

Comment: Works indeed, many thanks!